# FileUtils have to use new?

Tags: file-io, firefox-addon

With [FileUtils](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/FileUtils.jsm), do we have to use the the new word before it?

```
var f = new FileUtils.File(mypath);
```

Can't we just do:

```
var f = FileUtils.File(mypath);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current Firefox version you can simply call `FileUtils.File()` as a function and you will get the same result. However, this is an implementation detail - the documentation clearly says that `FileUtils.File()` is a constructor and should be used as such, with the `new` keyword. So while you can use it as a function, you cannot really rely on this behavior - it might stop working if the implementation changes in future. More importantly, logically this is a constructor that creates a new object, using it as such makes the code easier to understand.

Comment: Ah I see what about `getFile`? How can i tell if its a constructor or not? `var IniPathStr = FileUtils.getFile('DefProfRt', [dirName]);`

Comment: @Noitidart: You can read documentation - it lists it as a regular method. Or you can look at the name, the convention is that method names start with a lowercase letter whereas class names are uppercased.